# What is the definitive iPhone X corner radius?

Tags: iphone, xcode, screen

I've been experimenting and have found no conclusive corner radius for the iPhone X.

- Some sources, such as [iPhone X Screen Demystified - PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-x-screen-demystified), say its 40pts.
- Some say it's 44, like [UI Design for iPhone X: Top Elements and the Notch - Max Rudberg](http://blog.maxrudberg.com/post/166045445103/ui-design-for-iphone-x-top-elements-and-the-notch).

Using Xcode, I created a circle with a width and length of 80 (so radius 40), and put it in the top left corner of the iPhone X (so x and y are zero), there is a tiny white gap between the circle and the the edge of the screen, which you can see here:

[image]

I also tried another method, doing this with a button:

```
button.frame.size.height = 812
button.frame.size.width = 375
button.layer.cornerRadius = 40
button.center = self.view.center
```

With this I am left with:

[image]
[image]

So the question is, what is the real corner radius? Or what is going on with Xcode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

iPhone X corners do not *have* a conclusive corner radius. They're not normal arcs, they are ‘**continuous corners**’.

You can't replicate these with a simple .cornerRadius, and you also can't use Apple's own continuous corners, since that's a private API.

> CALayer on iOS 11 has a private "continuousCorners" property, which is what powers many rounded corners in SpringBoard – and likely more! Now I'm jealous.
>
> [image]

https://twitter.com/argentumko/status/955773459463790592

The closest you can get without your own implementation is UIBezierPath's rounded rectangle drawing, which uses `_continuousRoundedRectBezierPath`.

Comment: thank you so much this makes so much more sense now

Answer (score 5):

[Brad Ellis](https://medium.com/@BradEllis) has [an article detailing the curves on the iPhone X](https://medium.com/tall-west/no-cutting-corners-on-the-iphone-x-97a9413b94e).

> [..] iPhone X rounded screen corners don’t use the classic rounding method where you move in a straight line and then arc using a single quadrant of a circle. Instead, the math is a bit more complicated. Commonly called a squircle, the slope starts sooner, but is more gentle.

You can see the difference here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following Objective-C line

```c
NSLog(@"%@", [self traitCollection]);
```

executed in the iOS 11.0.1 simulator on the iPhone X produces the following output:

```
<UITraitCollection: ... _UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius = 39.000000>
```

So it looks like at *some point* in time, *somebody* at Apple thought the corner radius was 39 points. I guess that's the most *official* answer we'll get. :-) But as the other answers explain, that information is not very useful...

Even more useless information: Some other iOS 11.0 and 11.1 simulators report `_UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius = 0.000000` for iPhones without round corners (e.g. see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639547/is-horizontal-size-class-still-compact-for-iphone-7-plus-on-landscape)), but the simulator for iOS 12.2 does *not* include the `_UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius` property in the log output for `UITraitCollection`, and neither does a real iPhone X running iOS 11.2.1. I guess they removed this property from the log output in iOS 11.2 or so.

P.S.: I guess it doesn't matter, but I got these results on Xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 3):

The shape of the corners cannot be described as an arc. It can however be reproduced using public API since iOS 11. `UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect:cornerRadius:)` will create a rectangle with continuous rounded corners.

Source: https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/continuous-rounded-corners-with-uikit-b575d50ab232

iOS 13 introduced an explicit `cornerCurve` property on CALayer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayercornercurve